# Is there a way to obtain size of function and allocate memory for it to be copied and executed?

Tags: c++, c, function, sizeof, dynamic-memory-allocation

In C or C++, can one obtain the size occupied by a function, allocate memory dynamically with `malloc()` for it, make a copy, and execute it with a function pointer cast?

Am just curious about it, and here is a non-working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    void *printf_copy = malloc(sizeof(printf));
    ((int(*)(const char *, ...))printf_copy)("%s\n", "hello, world");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"obtain the size occupied by a function"* - Unlikely. *"allocate memory dynamically with `malloc()` for it, make a copy"* - Yes. *"execute it with a function pointer cast"* - Probably not by default on most OSes, as writable memory pages are typically not executable by default for security reasons.

Comment: There are things which might not work in a copy of code, for example relative jumps/calls to code outside the same code. Also, code might not be executable where you copy it to or it might be impossible to copy to memory where you can execute it.

Comment: You don't need to *copy* a function to use a pointer to it.

Comment: What exactly is it you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I was exploring ideas and I was merely curious about that one.

Comment: Part of the problem is assuming that a function _has_ a size. Especially in C++, this is becoming a flawed assumption, but with Profile Guided Optimization even C functions can be fragmented.

Comment: @MSalters: That is not only true for C++, but also for C. Just consider inlined functions which have no distinct "body" anymore.

Comment: Yes - functions must have an entry point, return type and parameter set.  That's it's really.  You can't tell, (in general), where they go, what they will do or even if they wil ever return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can't get size of the code used by a function such a way, there is no C operator or function for this. The only way is to get it from ELF headers, etc. Beware that a function may call others, so you usually need some kind of linking... and that function code may not be relative!

Second, the only way to get some executable memory is through `mmap`, `malloc` only gives you heap memory which is usually not executable part of the process space.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the code is self-modifying, (and if it is, you've been a very bad developer), there is no point in copying a function, even if you could safely do so - the copied would always look exactly the same as teh original, so why do it?  There are lots of reasons to avoid trying, as explained by others.

If you want to execute a function via a pointer, just call it where it is.  If you want it to have its own execution, thread it off.